# how to use clientX in angular2?

Tags: angular, observable

I tried to use the Observable to monitor the clientX of the element.
like this:

```
`const wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
 const body = document.body;

 const mouseDown = Observable.fromEvent(wrap, 'mousedown');
 const mouseUp = Observable.fromEvent(body, 'mouseup');
 const mouseMove = Observable.fromEvent(body, 'mousemove');

 mouseDown
  .map(event => mouseMove.takeUntil(mouseUp))
  .concatAll()
  .map(m => ({ x: m.event.clientX , y:m.clientY }))
  .subscribe(pos => {
    wrap.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
    wrap.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
  })`
```

but I got a error in `.map(m => ({ x: m.event.clientX , y:m.clientY }))`

said`Property 'event' does not exist on type '{}'`

how could I fix it?

Comment: I try to add an annotation as a generic param but not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line

```
.map(m => ({ x: m.event.clientX , y:m.clientY }))
```

to this

```
.map(m => ({ x: m.clientX , y:m.clientY }))
```

It's just a simple typo.

Comment: I did find myself writing event less, but I found still need adding a type declaration to `M`.thank you